# How to print MS word document in grayscale using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word

This is how I'm printing MS word document using Office.Interop

```
Application wordApp = new Application { Visible = false };
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(tempFilePath, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wordDoc.PrintOut();
wordDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
```

This outputs a color print from the default printer.
Now, I want to force printer to print this document in `Grayscale`.

There is a setting `wordApp.ActivePrinter` which is just a `string`. Other than that, I'm not able to find any path to achieve this. Can anybody recommend the way to handle this?

Comment: How would you do it in straight-up Word (i.e., open the Word app and do it). Where is the checkbox that allows you to do this?  Is it in Word, is it in a standard piece of Windows UI, or is it in a print driver-specific UI?

Comment: @Flydog57 Usually Grayscale option belongs to printer preferences. Not belongs to MS word. It doesn't matter option belongs to which application. Just I want to print a doc in Grayscale.

Comment: my point is that if you know where the checkbox is, you are more likely to find out how to set it from code. If it's printer-driver-specific, you may never figure it out